# Devise compatibility issue on Nginx server with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, devise

I have just installed devise on my Ruby on Rails project, it worked perfect on localhost, but when i did the same on Live Server then it started throwing me following error:

```
undefined method `devise_for' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007facfbc96e18>
```

i have already restarted the Nginx server by using this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

but no effect.

Thanks.

**Note:**
Rails version is `Rails 4.2.7.1`
Ruby version is `ruby 2.2.4p230`

Comment: Has the gem Devise installed in live server?

Comment: @Pavan yes.....

Comment: it created devise.rb file in config/initializers folder

Comment: restart again .. and hope gem was not in dev env

Comment: no it's not in dev env, and i restarted again, still same result

Comment: `bundle install` ? restart rails server ? Obviously, you have no Devise loaded into prod Rails server env. And Nginx is not an issue source either

Answer (score 0):

Aha! finally...

I just stop and start the `puma` and it's started working. I ran the following commands:

```
ps aux | grep puma   
kill -s SIGUSR2 17562   
bundle exec puma -e development -d -b unix:///home/democraticags/digitalammo/shared/sockets/puma.sock
```

Anyways thanks to all of you who devoted their precious time :)

Comment: Nice Live Server: '... -e development ...' :) Anyway, there is something wrong with your deploy